# React Native Duplicate RUN / DEBUG config - URL not found

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, metro-bundler

I am using react native: `0.61.5`

I am trying to simply switch the Run Phase for `iOS` that points to `Debug` to a new configuration, `DebugQA`

I have duplicated the `Debug` configuration to `DebugQA` and everything works great except when the app launches.  It crashes with:

```
No bundle URL present.\n\nMake sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.
```

I have made sure the metro bundler is running and if I switch the Run configuration back to `Debug` it works fine.  It's almost as if the metro bundler is not serving out the bundle / the new config isn't making the `GET` for the bundle from the metro bundler.

I've had success building other packages using this method however never creating a new config that tries to connect to metro bundler.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: It's been a while since you posted the question. Were you able to find a solution?